# Andengine- autoparallaxbackground- change speed of background

Tags: android, andengine

This is the autoparallaxbackgroundexample code of andengine-
I want to change the speed of the parallax background as it runs, something like a free run game like jetpack joyride..

The link for the code is-
[AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java)

The line where the speed and position of background is set is-

```
autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mParallaxLayerBack.getHeight(), this.mParallaxLayerBack)));
            autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-5.0f, new Sprite(0, 80, this.mParallaxLayerMid)));
            autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-10.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mParallaxLayerFront.getHeight(), this.mParallaxLayerFront)));
            scene.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);
```

I need to change the -5.0f value such that it increments after a fixed amount of time while the game is running..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method:

```
public void setParallaxChangePerSecond(final float pParallaxChangePerSecond)
```